# How to get average value of last 3 records for each records groups using BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with `ids` and `values`.
I want to get average value of last 3 record for each id.

```
WITH t0 as (SELECT 1 as bigid, 1 as id, 10 as value
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 1, 14 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 1, 18 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 1, 11 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 5, 1, 13 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 6, 1, 14 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 7, 2, 19 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 8, 2, 19
UNION ALL 
SELECT 9, 2, 11 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 10, 2, 13 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 11, 2, 14 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 12, 2, 19 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 13, 3, 19)
SELECT id, AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) FROM t0
```

This query returns results for each record inside window. How to get average value of last 3 records for each id?

Expected output

[image]

Comment: Your table is missing a critical third column which would tell us what "last" value means.

Comment: thank you for reply. Updated with `bigid` as serial number of record

Comment: What is your _exact_ output based on this input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you wanted just 1 row per every id:

```
WITH t0 as (
  SELECT 1 as bigid, 1 as id, 10 as value UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 1, 14 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3, 1, 18 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4, 1, 11 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5, 1, 13 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 6, 1, 14 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 7, 2, 19 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 8, 2, 19 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 9, 2, 11 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 10, 2, 13 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 11, 2, 14 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 12, 2, 19 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 13, 3, 19
),
last3 AS (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(value ORDER BY bigid DESC LIMIT 3) as values
  FROM t0
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT 
  id,
  (SELECT AVG(x) FROM UNNEST(values) x) AS avg
FROM last3
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your current query is correct except that it is missing an `ORDER BY` clause in the call to `AVG`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY bigid
                  ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) avg_last_3
    FROM t0
)

SELECT DISTINCT id, avg_last_3
FROM cte
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: I this case query returns result of average value of currant and 2 previous rows for each row in window. But I need to get only 3 rows
 id and  average of last 3 row

Comment: `MAX` doesn't work cuz some previous average values higher than last 3 records

Comment: @Timogavk Please review the latest edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you're looking for is this

```sql
WITH t0 as (SELECT 1 as bigid, 1 as id, 10 as value
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 1, 14 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 1, 18 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 1, 11 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 5, 1, 13 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 6, 1, 14 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 7, 2, 19 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 8, 2, 19
UNION ALL 
SELECT 9, 2, 11 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 10, 2, 13 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 11, 2, 14 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 12, 2, 19 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 13, 3, 19),

avgs as (
SELECT 
  id, 
  bigid,
  value,
  AVG(value) OVER (last_3_window ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) avg
FROM t0
WINDOW last_3_window AS (partition by id ORDER BY bigid)),

max_bigid as (
  select id, max(bigid) as max_bigid 
  from t0 group by 1)

select a.id, a.avg 
  from max_bigid m 
  left join avgs a on m.id = a.id and a.bigid = m.max_bigid
```

The step that you're not having is the join with the latest bigid for each of the ids